# Storing results of a game in a sqlite table

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

This is a section of code in a program I have created to store and review the results of a game based upon the "class_number" the user gives. This section is very bulky and I was wondering how I could make it more efficient.

```
if class_number in ['1','2','3']:
    if class_number == 1:
        query = """
         INSERT INTO CLASS1    VALUES
              (?, ?, ?)
            """
elif class_number == 2:
        query = """
         INSERT INTO CLASS2    VALUES
              (?, ?, ?)
            """
elif class_number == 3:
        query = """
         INSERT INTO CLASS3    VALUES
              (?, ?, ?)
            """
```

Comment: When you have this kind of problem, it's most likely because your database schema is poorly designed. Can you describe your database schema in more detail? What are these "classes"? What are the columns in the tables?

Comment: I'm relatively new to python so a poor design is probably to blame. The game is a test for a school so the 'class_number' is the name of each child's class. The columns in the tables are the child's name, the child's score and the date they took the test. But when reviewing the scores, each 'Class' needs to be separate, this is why I needed 3 different tables. Does that help at all?

Comment: Yes, that's clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difficulty you are having in the Python code is just a symptom of the underlying problem here, which the design of the database schema.

At the moment, you have multiple tables, one for each class, something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE class1 (name TEXT, score INT, date TEXT);
CREATE TABLE class2 (name TEXT, score INT, date TEXT);
CREATE TABLE class3 (name TEXT, score INT, date TEXT);
```

but this is starting to cause trouble because you have the class number in a variable and need to choose which table to look in.

The solution is to represent the class as data along with the other fields, something like this:

```sql
-- A record in this table means that a named student got a score
-- in a test for a class on a date.
CREATE TABLE test_score (class INT, name TEXT, score INT, date TEXT);
```

Now it's easy to add a new score to the table:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO test_score (class, name, score, date) '
          'VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', (class_number, name, score, date))
```

In your comment, you wrote, "when reviewing the scores, each 'Class' needs to be separate", but that can easily be done using a database query:

```
# Get all the scores for class_number
c.execute('SELECT name, score, date FROM test_score WHERE class=?',
          (class_number,))
for name, score, date in c.fetchall():
    print('{} scored {} on {}'.format(name, score, date))
```

I can see some other difficulties that are likely to arise as you develop this program:

1. What if two students have the same name? How will you avoid their test scores getting muddled up?
2. What if a class needs to have two tests on the same day? How will you distinguish these?
3. How are the scores entered into the database? Does someone have to type them in? If so, what happens if there are mistakes (or insignificant differences) in the data entry? For example, a student gets entered as "Jane Doe" in one record and "Jane J. Doe" in another?

These are common problems in database design, and so there are standard ways to solve them (the techniques are known as "database normalization"). But going into this now would probably be too much detail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my next step will be to look into creating a 'primary key' field in my table to prevent some of the issues you have mentioned. Thank you for taking the time to help me with my problem.